# Check if ArrayList of Strings contains 50 different Strings one by one

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist

How to check if ArrayList of strings contains every of 50 different strings from string array one by one and for every identical string in ArrayList to do something?

Comment: can you show us what you've done?

Comment: Can I do it with double for loop maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function to check if all Strings in your array are also in the ArrayList. If you want to add additional logic, like doSomething() each time a match is found, you should be able to adapt the code easily.

```
ArrayList myList; // let's assume its initialized and filled with Strings
String[] strArray; // let's assume its initialized and filled with Strings

//this function returns true if all Strings in the array are also in your arraylist

public boolean containsAll(myList, strArray){
  //iterate your String array
  for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
    if(!myList.contains(strArray[i])){
      //String is not in arraylist, no need to check the rest of the Strings
      return false;
    }
  }
 return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use LINQ?

```
    List<String> duplicates = YourList.GroupBy(x => x)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .Select(g => g.Key)
                         .ToList();
```

Note that this will return all duplicates in a new `List<string>` , so if you want only want to know which items are duplicated in the source list, you could apply Distinct to the resulting sequence or use the solution given above